# How to maintain two or more divergent branches that never merge?

Tags: git, workflow, branch

I'm maintaining a [Redis Sentinel library for Laravel](https://github.com/monospice/laravel-redis-sentinel-drivers) in git with two active development branches:

```
1.x   ... o ———— o —————— o — o — o — o — o ...
           ↘              ↑   ↑     ↖
2.x   (breaking change) — o — o — o — o — o ...
```

As illustrated above, I forked *1.x* to accomodate breaking changes from a newer version of the framework that this library integrates with, but I find myself `cherry-pick`ing commits or manually copying code between branches that update common functionality in both branches.

It seems like I can never merge these branches because they each contain code that is not compatible with the other. What better workflow can I follow to reduce the effort needed to merge common changes between the branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The age-old question.  To branch or not to branch.

There really is no magic bullet here.  What is the reason they must stay diverged?  If they are meant to never come back together, due to something like new architecture implementation, then is there a reason you can't migrate 1.x into 2.x or completely deprecate 1.x after an announced period of time, etc.?

These are normally the hard choices that must be made - deprecate and stop supporting an older or divergent change because of the maintenance overhead associated with constant merging, or just live with it.  Just realize if you live with it, you are spending time on that overhead that could have otherwise been spent on new features.

The longer a branch stays divergent with no plan to reconcile the differences, the more technical debt you are likely to have keeping you busy on a regular basis, and likely growing.

I realize it's not much of a solution, but I don't know of any other options - if you are going to allow differences without a plan to remerge them in the future, there will be differences and constant maintainence will be required for whatever you do want to keep the same.  I don't know of any other answer without getting into the nitty-gritty details of your particular project.

Comment: Thanks for the sound advice. This is as I feared. The *1.x* branch is deprecated for the end of the year, but I was hoping to learn some trick or workflow for the future. The branches cannot merge because they each depend on external code that changed between versions (and package manager metadata that constrains each branch to these versions). I'll leave this open for a bit longer, but I expect this is the best answer possible for these situations.

Comment: In the case of external dependency differences, can you implement an interface or use some other method of allowing the code to choose, either at compile time, or at run-time, which version of the external library it is?  This would actually be a means of merging them back together - and would separate the code for each version in a way that should make updates easier.  However, it may not be worth the effort, especially if you are deprecating 1.x at the end of 2017.

Comment: I could, and I do use this approach for minor incompatibilities between the framework versions that the project needs to support, but, in this case the differences are substantial enough that I didn't see value in doing so. Too many runtime conditions (it's PHP, after all) would introduce complexity and overhead that I don't think I can justify just to coerce the code into one branch. Thanks again for your time--I feel better about the decision to fork after reading your suggestions. I guess I was looking for that magic bullet! You've given me some things to think about for future projects.

Comment: I don't agree that one has to "live with it".  Subversion tracks merges on a per-commit basis.  I.e. it tracks that commit X has already been merged from branch A to branch B, and if I repeat the merge command later, it will not try to merge commit X again.  Git could be extended to do the same.

Comment: @hibbelig Git does the same, on a per file (or per line?) basis. It auto-merges and you will only get a conflict if there has been a change in the same part of a file for both branches since they split at the base commit (or since the last common merge).